# How to change the location of admin notice in html without using Javascript?

Tags: hooks, notices

I am adding an admin notice via the conventional `admin_notice` hook in my plugin:

```
function my_admin_notice() { ?>
    <div class="notice notice-info is-dismissible">
        <p><?php _e( 'some message', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}

if ( my_plugin_show_admin_notice() )
  add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice' );
```

How can I control where wordpress places the admin notice, in the html on the current screen, without using Javascript?

Comment: Can you elaborate where do you want to put the admin notice ?

Comment: @sumit Sorry, I meant location as in the html on the page itself in a custom page.

Comment: You wrote this `if ( /* some condition */ )` leads to confusions!

Comment: @hitautodestruct i updated my answer to your new question.

Comment: @Sumit I updated my answer. I just didn't want the focus to go away from the fact that I am asking about admin notices.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found out by accident recently that all the notices will be moved to after the first `<h2>` tag on the page inside a `<div class="wrap">`. This gives you some *slight* control in that, for example, on a plugin settings page you can put an empty `<h2></h2>` at the very top if you want to use `<h2>Plugin Title</h2>` without it messing up the display formatting there.

**Update**: As some have noted, at some point this was changed so that it is now after either the `h1` OR `h2` tag inside the div with class `wrap` where the notices are inserted, in that order (ie. with *first* preference for `h1` if it exists.) For reference, anyone looking for the actual javascript doing this can find it in `/wp-admin/js/common.js`:

```
    /*
     * The `.below-h2` class is here just for backward compatibility with plugins
     * that are (incorrectly) using it. Do not use. Use `.inline` instead. See #34570.
     * If '.wp-header-end' is found, append the notices after it otherwise
     * after the first h1 or h2 heading found within the main content.
     */
    if ( ! $headerEnd.length ) {
        $headerEnd = $( '.wrap h1, .wrap h2' ).first();
    }
    $( 'div.updated, div.error, div.notice' ).not( '.inline, .below-h2' ).insertAfter( $headerEnd );
```

Also as you can see there if you don't want your own notice to be moved just give it a class of `inline` and it will be excluded.

Comment: This is the closest to controlling the placement. Wordpress supposedly does something internally to see where the <h*> tag is and places it there.

Comment: @majick nice catch +1

Answer (score 2):

According to the Codex `admin_notice` does the following:

> Notices displayed near the top of admin pages. The hook function
>   should echo a message to be displayed.

That means you cannot place them at the bottom or middle of your screen, if you use the hook. Furthermore if you place a div with the class notice anywhere in your admin pages, WP admin JS scripts will put them just where all the other notices would be; and they will behave like notices too.

FYI: I tested this already with a fresh install. ;)

### But

If you want to show a `admin_notice` at a particular page, you can add the action within a `current_screen` action:

```
function my_admin_notice() { ?>
    <div class="notice notice-info is-dismissible">
        <p><?php _e( 'some message', 'my_textdomain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function my_current_screen_example( $current_screen ) {
    // All your conditions go here, e.g. show notice @ post (not page) edit/new
    if ( 'post' == $current_screen->post_type && 'post' == $current_screen->base ) {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice' );
    }
}

add_action( 'current_screen', 'my_current_screen_example' );
```

### More Information:

- Action Hook: [admin_notices](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices)
- Action Hook: [current_screen](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/current_screen)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question ? :P

Comment: @Sumit How come? His question after his code: _How can I control where wordpress places the admin notice without using Javascript?_

Comment: Sorry my bad I did not see :)

Comment: @iantsch Your answer is helpful but not what I intended. I want to control placement of the admin notice in the html. majick's answer helps me do that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I resolved it by ensuring all the heading tags above where I want to place the notice there is no `<h2>`.

In this case, I wanted to display an error log notice below the input field as shown below : 
[image]

I solved it by introducing an empty `<h2>` tag just below the email input field and also change the tabs tag to `<h3>` instead of `<h2>`

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this issue and tried using the empty `<h2></h2>` method and it didn't work for me. Eventually I discovered that using `<hr class="wp-header-end">` seems to work and the admin notice will always appear directly below it.

Hopefully it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

The action `admin_notices` is called or applied **only once** in the file, `admin-header.php` on line number 238, just at the beginning of the `wpbody-content` div, which makes up the body of a dashboard page. Hence, there is no way you can change the position of the admin notice, without using JavaScript. However, you can definitely make your own `notice` divs at the positions or locations you want, and manipulate their visibility.

Just create the mark up for the notice as:

```
<div class="notice notice-info is-dismissible">
    <p>This is a notice.</p>
</div>
```

You can now control it's visibility using PHP. Meaning when you redirect a user to this page, or submit a form on this page, just set the message in the div, and using a simple if else, echo the div.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `settings_errors()` will display all notices that I've tested with a settings form so far. Despite the name it also outputs success messages. Place it anwhere in your template and that's where the notices will appear.

I found the `<h2>` solution mentioned to not do anything.

[WordPress Reference settings_errors()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/settings_errors/)